# Как создать стэк в Java, не используя стандартный класс Stack?

Tags: java

Как создать стэк в Java, не используя стандартный класс Stack?

Comment: См. вопрос (прямо рядом) о создании своего списка в java. По сути это очень похоже.

Comment: Бывают же такие "волны" вопросов =) может это в школах домашние на информатике в понедельник задают?))

Comment: @Gorets, обычное университетское задание. Думаю, многие занимались тем же самым на первом курсе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще непонятно, чем не устраивает стандартный класс. Если очень нужно, то

1. либо взять другой пакет,
2. либо реализовать самостоятельно.

Например, залезть в [исходники](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Stack.java.html), просмотреть реализацию и переписать под себя. Пример:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomStack<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public void push(T o) {
        add(o);
    }

    public T pop() {
        return remove(size() - 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Привет, очень интересный ответ (ссылка исходники). 

Поглядел и понял, что возможная эффективность реализации (коллекций основанных на массиве объектов (реально там много копирования в **новый** объект)) может обуславливаться только **нетривиальной** реализацией public static native void arraycopy() (определен в http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/System.java.html).

Ссылки на исходники native у Вас случайно нет ? Очень интересно.

Comment: имхо так было бы лучше:

    public class CustomStack<T>
    {
        private ArrayList<T> = new ArrayList<T>();
        public void push(T o) { l.add(o); }
        public T pop() { return l.remove(l.size() - 1) ; }
    }

Comment: @jmu чем?) тем что ты ArrayList юзаешь не по назначению? кстати, пропустил l

Comment: А почему бы не сделать через LinkedList и не сравнить на разных режимах как со стандартной реализацией (через Vector), так и с предлагаемой на ArrayList (по сути Vector, но без syncronized методов) ?

Если и в самом деле обычное университетское задание (комментарий @Angry Bird), то получилось  бы неплохое исследование. И студенту плюс и обществу ХэшКода (если результаты опубликует) польза.

Comment: 2Gorets во первых это не я. во вторых "не по назначению" это еще под сомнением, - если оставить методы листа тогда стек перестанет быть стеком. хотя конечно-же лучше было бы linked list использовать

p.s. пропущеная буква при отсутсвии IDE это не ошибка :)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [`Collections.asLifoQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#asLifoQueue-java.util.Deque-) можно из [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) сделать стэк (если быть точным, то [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) с логикой [LIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO), эквивалентную стэку):

```
Queue<String> stack = Collections.asLifoQueue(new ArrayDeque<>());
```

В полученном объекте будут корректно для стэка работать все методы `Queue`.

```
stack.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
//e
System.out.println(stack.peek());
//edcba
stack.forEach(element -> System.out.print(element));
```

Собственно, это наиболее приемлемый способ создания стэка, используя классы JDK. Класс `Stack` использовать не рекомендуется (см. [Класс Stack в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669975/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-stack-%D0%B2-java/))