# Класс Stack в Java

Tags: java, list, коллекции, стек

Какой класс лучше использовать для использования стека в java и почему он лучше?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Deque

Для стэка рекомендуется использовать реализации интерфейса [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). Интерфейс включает методы стэка: `push`, `poll` и `peek`.

Стандартные реализации перечислены в документации, например:

- [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) — дэк на основе массива;
- [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) — связный список;
- [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) — потокобезопасная реализация.

Выбор класса зависит от логики приложения (какие операции выполняются и как часто, как изменяется размер стэка) и потребует оценки производительности.

В документации к `ArrayDeque`  утверждается, что в качестве очереди он, скорее всего, будет быстрее `LinkedList`:

> ... This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.

так что, если не требуется доступ из нескольких потоков, разумно будет использовать `ArrayDeque` по умолчанию.

Методы `poll` и `peek` в `Deque` унаследованы от [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) и работают в последовательности для очереди ([FIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)). Для симуляции работы стэка можно использовать вместо них методы [`pollLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#pollLast--) и [`peekLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#peekLast--).

### Queue

Более удобный вариант: с помощью метода [`Collections.asLifoQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#asLifoQueue-java.util.Deque-) преобразовать `Deque` в объект `Queue`, который ведет себя как стэк ([LIFO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO)). В этом случае будут корректно работать все методы и итераторы. Также не будут доступны лишние, не допустимые для стэка операции:

```
 Queue<String> stack = Collections.asLifoQueue(new ArrayDeque<>());
 stack.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
 //edcba
 stack.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));
```

### Stack не рекомендуется использовать

Также есть стандартный класс [`java.util.Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), но его не рекомендуется использовать. Из документации:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example: `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`
>
> Более полный и согласованный набор LIFO операций предоставляется через интерфейс `Deque` и его реализации, которые должны использоваться вместо этого класса. Например: `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`

т.е. класс сохранен для обратной совместимости, но вместо него нужно использовать реализации `Deque`. Это вызвано историческими причинами: в первой версии Java в реализации `Stack` допущены ошибки, например:

- `Stack` — конкретный класс, в отличие от остальных базовых коллекций, которые представлены интерфейсами: `Set`, `List`, `Queue`;
- класс наследуется от `Vector`, что концептуально неверно (поддерживаются лишние операции).

Подробнее о проблемах `Stack`:

- [Why Stack extends Vector in JDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314298/why-stack-extends-vector-in-jdk)
- [What are the negative aspects of Java class Stack inheriting from Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922257/what-are-the-negative-aspects-of-java-class-stack-inheriting-from-vector)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень хорошо изложил.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется стоит использовать `ArrayList` или `LinkedList`. Второй будет использовать больше памяти, но зато операция добавления элемента в нём работает честные `O(1)`, в отличии от `ArrayList`, у которого `O(1)` амортизированные. Не следует использовать класс `Stack`, потому что в нём все методы помечены как `synchronized`, что замедляет производительность в случае, если ваш стек использует только один поток (почти всегда именно так и происходит).

Comment: Кроме Stack класса, есть ли в java еще реализаций именно стека?

Answer (score 0):

Есть мнение - авторитетное - от одного из авторов красно-черных деревьев, что встроенные коллекции в java очень наворочены. Они напоминают швейцарские ножи - многое умеют. Но обратная сторона этого - не все операции имеют одинаковую алгоритмическую сложность. Поэтому лучше использовать коллекции с меньшим количеством методов, но которые хорошо используются именно вашей задаче. Посмотрите альтернативные реализации стека - не останавливайтесь на стандартной библиотеке.